# Outlook - VBA to return content of form controls

Tags: forms, vba, outlook

can anyone guid me in the right direction how I can inspect a particular outlook message (which is a custom form), get the value of textboxes, checkboxes etc. and assign them to a variable in vba? I have the code which will follow to parse that info to excel but i need the first part :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your message is a custom form it means that its body in HTML format so all you need to do is fetch your message and than access its HTMLBody property: (C#)

```
Outlook.MailItem mail = //get your item here (you could identify it by EntryID/Conversation index or just filter your folder for mails with particular subject)

string htmlBody = malil.HTMLBody;
```

//Here you need to parse your HTML and get all the information you need

Here are some usefull links:

[MailItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870912%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Folder.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864247%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx)